# Ругается на нужную скобку

Tags: ajax, javascript

Ошибка:  `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ) на последней строке`

Код:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#mainform').submit(function(){
        var id = jQuery("input#id").val();
        var pass = jQuery("input#pass").val();

        var dataString = 'id='+ id + '&pass=' + pass;

        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "public/auth.php",
            data: dataString,
            success:  function() {
                jQuery('#mainform').hide();
                jQuery('#response').html("<p class = 'success-box'>Успешная авторизация</p>");
            });  
        }
    });
    return false;
});
</script>
```

Т.е. ему скобка не нравится, однако она, по логике, да и вообще, должна тут быть.

Что ему не нравится-то?

Comment: я скоро выпущу десять скрижалей (виртуальных), на одной из которых будет написано "форматируйте отступы кода"

видите ли, если IDE мне подсетит нужные скобки, то хэшкод все-таки не IDE, а создавать проект на каждый вопрос несколько накладно

Comment: @Etki юмор оценил. Спасибо. 
В IDE эта скобочка подсвечивается вместе с парной, т.е., тут всё в порядке, а вот консоль ругается сюда. 
Подсвечивая скобочки на ф-х тоже всё нормально находится

Comment: @Виталий RS меняйте IDE (и форматируйте отступы), что тут сказать

![Imgur](http://i.imgur.com/OR6ourj.png)

upd: а, не, проблема еще выше - success-коллбэк закрывается неверно

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Форматируйте код - и снизойдёт на вас просветление:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#mainform').submit(function(){

        var id = jQuery("input#id").val();
        var pass = jQuery("input#pass").val();

        var dataString = 'id='+ id + '&pass=' + pass;

        jQuery.ajax({  
            type: "POST",  
            url: "public/auth.php",  
            data: dataString,
            success:  function() {  
                jQuery('#mainform').hide();  
                jQuery('#response').html("<p class = 'success-box'>Успешная авторизация</p>");   
            });  // <--- скобка и точка с запятой не на своём месте
        } 
    });  
    return false;
});
```